# Shifting every element in C++ array to the left

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to write a function delete an element in a C++ array, that is, shift every element one to the left, starting at the index.

The code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 50;

void fill_array(char array[], int &current_size, const int max_size);

void print_array(const char array[], const int current_size);

int delete_index(char array[], int &current_size, int index);

int main () {

    char array[MAX_SIZE] = {' '};
    int current_size = 0;
    fill_array(array, current_size, MAX_SIZE);
    int index = 4;
    delete_index(array, current_size, index);
    cout << "After deleting element at index " << index << " the array is: ";
    print_array(array, current_size);

    return 0;
}

int delete_index(char array[], int &current_size, int index) {
    // Check input
    if (index > current_size) {
        cout << "Index must be between 0 and " << current_size - 1 << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < current_size; i++) {
        cout << "array[" << index << "] = " << index << endl;
        array[index] = array[index + 1];
    }
    current_size--;
    cout << current_size << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the output I get when inputting "thisisnotworking" and index 4 is:

```
Please input characters for the array (max of 50) or enter '*' to quit: 
onetwothree*
array[4] = 4
array[4] = 4
array[4] = 4
array[4] = 4
array[4] = 4
array[4] = 4
array[4] = 4
10
After deleting element at index 4 the array is: onetoothre
```

I don't understand it is not increasing the index in the for loop.

I've read similar questions here and elsewhere but couldn't fix the problem still. Any idea why this is?

NOTE: I only want to use arrays (not vectors, etc.).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: no! let's say size is 10; so array[9] = array[9 + 1]  = array[10]: array[10] is not an element of the array. so you are assigning garbage values. to solve this you should take in account out of boundary issues. size-- is just trick for the loop to print. but the real size is constant of an array. 10 is 10

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at the resources you passed. I didn't include the remaining functions because they're self-explanatory and I didn't think they'd be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int i = index; i < current_size; i++) {
    cout << "array[" << index << "] = " << index << endl;
    array[index] = array[index + 1];
    }
```

Your loop counter is `i`. Inside your loop, you should use `i` instead of `index`

Corrected:

```
    for (int i = index; i < current_size; i++) {
    cout << "array[" << i << "] = " << array[i] << endl;
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `array[index] = array[index + 1]` while you need `array[i] = array[i + 1]`
It's the same here: `cout << "array[" << i << "] = " << i << endl;`

Comment: The line above: `cout << "array[" << index << "] = " << index << endl;`  should use `i` instead of `index` as well.

Comment: @C.H. Yep, gonna add this.

Answer (score 0):

use pointers to dynamically change the size:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int* ClearElement(int array[], int index, const int& SizeOrig, int& NewSize)
{
    array[index] = -1;
    NewSize = SizeOrig;
    NewSize--;

    int* ptrArray = new int[NewSize];
    if(!ptrArray)
        throw "No more memory!";

    for(int i(0), j(0); i < SizeOrig; i++)
    {
        if(-1 != array[i])
        {
            ptrArray[j] = array[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return ptrArray;
}


int main()
{

    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    int SizeOrig = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(int));
    int NewSize  = SizeOrig;

    int index;

    try{
            cout << "element index to clear: ";
            cin >> index;
            cout << endl;

            if(index < 0 || index > NewSize)
                throw "out of boundary index!";

            int* ptrArray = ClearElement(array, index, SizeOrig, NewSize);

            for(int i(0); i < NewSize; i++)
                cout << ptrArray[i] << ", "; 

            delete[] ptrArray;
        }
    catch(char* cp)
    {
        cout << cp << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "sorry an error has happened!";
        exit(1);
    }


    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use std::copy from algorithm

```
int max = 10;
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int index = 4;
std::copy(array+index+1, array+max, array+index);
```